# Universal Image Loader: Save current image to SD-Card?

Tags: android, image, save, android-viewpager

I'm using the Universal Image Loader library.I have a viewpager gallery of images and I want to be able to save the current image being viewed to the SD-Card. Below is the button i've implemented but it doesn't work.  PLEASE HELP!!

```
private ViewPager gallery;

public class ImageGalleryActivity extends BaseActivity {
final String[] imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
.....
  findViewById(R.id.btnSave).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int index = gallery.getCurrentItem();
                ImageView img = imageUrls.get(index);
                saveimage(img);

                Toast.makeText(ImageGalleryActivity.this, "Image Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://Pictures"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            }
        });


...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the appropriate permission in your app manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: its this line " ImageView img = imageUrls.get(index);  " causing the error

Answer (score 0):

Bundle is generally used for passing data between various Activities of android. It depends on you what type of values you want to pass but bundle can hold all types of values and pass to the new activity.

You can use it like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityName.class);
intent.putExtra("myKey",AnyValue);  
startActivity(intent);
```

Now you can get the passed values by...

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
String tmp = extras.getString("myKey");
```

Have below line inside onCreate method after

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    private static String imageURL;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

My best solution is don't pass anything via bundle to another activity.
Instead use this class,

```
public class MyGetSetMethod()
{
    String[] imageURLS;

    public void setImageURLS (String[] imageUrls) 
    {
        this.imageURLS = imageUrls;
    }

    public String[] getImageURLS() 
    {
        return imageURLS;
    } 
}
```

Now on your ImagePagerActivity,

```
MyGetSetMethod.setImageURLS(imageURLS);
```

On ImageGalleryActivity,

```
String[] ImageURLS = MyGetSetMethod.getImageUrls();
```

This should do.

Comment: im not sure where I should be putting the MyGetSetMethod?

Comment: Create a separate class file ie MyGetSetMethod.java and add those methods above.

Comment: its producing errors saying class or interface expect after the () ?

Comment: Major problem is in "ImageView img = imageUrls.get(index);" I'm not doing the right thing to get the image view correctly.

Comment: Post ImageGalleryActivity code, so that i can give solution.

Comment: ImageGalleryActivity is here http://pastebin.com/0PnXfNHb and ImagePagerActivity.java is here http://pastebin.com/B0TA99w1. THe save button is actually in ImagePagerActivity not in ImageGalleryActivity as the question says.

Comment: In ImagePagerActivity class

Comment: From which to which activity you want to send image urls string arrays?